Docker "(root) Additional property include is not allowed:" when creating base compose file
I create a docker compose for self-hosted services.
As there are a lot of services I decided to make a base compose file, which includes every service needed, so i can easily manage what i need and what i do not need.
I attach error and my base compose file.
docker-compose.yml
include:
  - path: 'jellyfin/docker-compose.jellyfin.yml'
  - path: 'trilium/docker-compose.trilium.yml'

result of docker compose up
PS C:\ss\ss\> docker compose up
(root) Additional property include is not allowed

The problem is that when I do "docker compose up" I receive "(root) Additional property include is not allowed"
I do not have any more "include" property anywhere.
Running on windows.
I am expecting my base docker-compose file to startup necessary services.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include the Compose file and the actual error message in plain text?

@DavidMaze just fixed it thanks. I updated question it might help someone esle who has old docker

I managed to beat this.
Answer is simple:

check docker compose version via 'docker compose version'
if the version is below 2.20, update docker compose.

Thanks
